# Properly setting default external PDF reader in emacs org-mode

Tags: linux, pdf, emacs

My default PDF viewer is Evince and I'm running Linux Mint 15 with Cinnamon. If, for instance, I double-click a PDF file on my Desktop, it opens in Evince as expected.

In my `org-file-apps` variable I have the line `("\\.pdf\\'" . default))`. However, when I open a `file:` link in org-mode, ever since I installed Okular, it uses that instead. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using? Cinnamon? Mate? Gnome?

Comment: Cinnamon. Problem solved but I still wonder what "default" got hijacked by Okular. Emacs documentation says the following about the default setting, but it's completely over my head:

`Use the default application for this file type, which is the association for t in the list, most likely in the system-specific
part. This can be used to overrule an unwanted setting in the system-specific variable.`

Comment: Likely installing Okular has triggered an entry here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_applications#XDG_standard

Comment: See also xdg-open configuration insights at [Configuring Org-mode to open PDFs with evince - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91057/configuring-org-mode-to-open-pdfs-with-evince)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably Okular has registered itself as the "default" somewhere; where and how depends on your desktop environment.

In any case, and assuming you don't wish to uninstall Okular, you can point Emacs to the PDF viewer of your choice by doing `M-x customize-variable RET org-file-apps RET`, then choosing "Command" as the value type for the cdr of the cons cell whose car is `\.pdf\'`, and setting the value to the command you want to run (in this case `evince`). Or, if you set `org-file-apps` outside of Customize, just replace `default` with e.g. `"evince"`, to run that command; see `C-h v org-file-apps` or `M-x describe-variable RET org-file-apps RET` for more details on how to set these values.

Comment: Thanks... The documentation in emacs for `org-file-apps` actually gives a few different examples of commands using evince, and I eventually figured out the one I needed was `evince %s`.